# Foundation 6 for sites: How to centralize anchor tags?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm trying to centralize an anchor tag in foundation 6, I've tried the [float-center](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/float-classes.html#float-center) class but instead of centralize it becomes expanded:

[image: wrong centering anchor]

My code

```
<div class="column">
  <!-- some html -->
  <a class="large success button float-center">Sign Up</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `float-center` have `display:block` css property. Remove `float-center`  from `a` tag and add `text-center` class in `column` div.

```
<div class="column text-center">
  <!-- some html -->
  <a class="large success button ">Sign Up</a>
</div>
```